# How to Disable IBAction Button, that is on subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

i have an IBAction button that is connected through connection inspector properly…

in '.h'

```
- (IBAction)Download;
```

also have a same name method in my '.m'

```
- (void) Download
{
// Code for data download   
}
```

when i pressed button its working perfectly fine for data download…

my problem is if user have limited support then they can't download the data… and obviously 
the the Download IBAction Button disabled…
and yes this Button is on subView.

what should i do for this issue… ???

Comment: unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Create an if-statement in your Download method that will check if somebody is allowed to execute that piece of code? That is, if I understood the question properly..

Comment: you can set the button's user interaction to False.

Comment: You can either disable the button or show a UILable saying network unavailability or hide the button.

Comment: @exceptionx0000f how i can do that ? will you please help me?

Comment: please post your code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i found useful is:

make IBOutlet Connection in ViewController's interface for the required button in storyboard.

```
IBOutlet UIButton *actionButton;
```

Now if you want to disable it.

```
actionButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

if you want to make it enable again

```
actionButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
yourbtn.enabled = NO;
```

to disable your button and when you want to enable use

```
yourbtn.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: Download is undeclared….

Answer (score 0):

create IBoutlet of the button through interface builder and set button's userinteractionenabled to NO.

In your download button action, do this

```
if(condition)
{
  //code to download
}
else
{
  [self.downloadButton setuserinteractionenabled : NO];
}
```

Comment: Bad receiver type Void

Comment: Are you writing the code in void method or in ibaction?? if in void method then are you calling that method in ibaction??

Comment: on button pressed this method is invoked

Comment: what i want is just to disable the this button

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you don't need to re-activate the button. If you need to re-activate you'll need to have an IBOutlet.

in your .h

```
- (IBAction)Download:(UIButton *)sender;
```

in your .m

```
   - (IBAction) Download:(UIButton *)sender {
      if (test not ok) {    
        sender.enabled = NO;
      } else {
        perform download....
      }
    }
```